# getApplicationContext() method cannot be resolved, LoginActivity.this is not an enclosing class

Tags: android

In the ProgressDialog initialization it is showing that LoginActivity.this is not an enclosing class.
In onPostExecute() method Toast is not getting executed and getApplicationContext() method cannot be resolved.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et1,et2;
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
}
public void login(View view)
{
    new BackgroundTask().execute(et1.getText().toString(),et2.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(this,"Button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}

class Background extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
{
   ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);;
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog.setMessage("Processing");
    progressDialog.setTitle("Title");
    progressDialog.show();
}

int check_point =0;
String resp="";
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.6/login.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String s;
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            resp=resp+s;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

    return check_point;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ACtivity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: How is login(View view) associated to the actual Button instance? Please, use Log instead of Toasts & System.out.print. Why do you initialize progressDialog out of the onPreExecute? Considering that the AsyncTask is an inner class of LoginActivity, why do you initialize progressDialog with the activity context, and use the Application context onPostExecute?

Comment: then what should I be doing?

Comment: i think using keyword "this" instead of "LoginActivity.this" should fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class Background is not an inner class. Its outside of the scope of the LoginActivity.
Thats why you're getting that error. Try moving it as an inner class.

```
classs ParentClass{
    //some fields, methods whatevenr

    class InnerClass{
       // this is inner
    }
}

class OutSideScope{
     // this is outside of the scope of the Parent Class
}
```

Happy coding ;)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot.  I didn't realize that and kept on worrying about why my code was not working. Thanks.